# How to display large data in tcl wish shell

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Rephrasing the question:

I am working on http rest calls and driving them via http package.
So i ran a http get request from http::getUrl method, which returns an array instance consisting the output.

When I do `parray $arrName` wish shell hangs, as the data is around in 50 mb.
It is working fine in TCL shell, since that show only the buffer output not the complete.

Any solution for doing page wise reading in wish.exe

Comment: AFAIK the text widget isn't really useful for that amount of text. It tries to do so many things to keep the text in order that it gets overloaded. I don't have any alternative to suggest, sorry.

Comment: You would have to create a pager.  Display the first megabyte of text and have next page and previous page buttons to move through and display the data.

Comment: @BradLanam agreed, this could be one of the way likewise we see in linux cmd line, press any key to populate page

Comment: Yeah unfortunately it seems like the solution Brad suggested is the only one. You'll have to just display pieces of the text at a time.

Comment: One thing I noticed. If wrap in set to none for the wish shell, then it shows the output response. But then I pressed "end" button to go to last character, wish shell hangs

Comment: Can `fcofigure stdout -buffersize`  or `fconfigure stdout -buffering` do the trick? Although I have tried, and not working. But if we have control over stdout buffer then it should work. Right?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way out of it -- with the amounts of data of this magnitude, you need to *paginate*... How exactly to do that depends on your budget (not money necessarily -- time and effort you have for this task), and the data format.

If the data is tabular, you may wish to utilize the [TkTable](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1877) widget. If it is in HTML, [TkHTML](http://tkhtml.tcl.tk/) may be called for. Simply dumping 50Mb worth of text to `stdout` is hardly useful -- a human user can't read through all that anyway. You either need to highlight the important parts or filter out the unimportant...

Comment: Actually data is in json format coming from a ReST call. This get call gets data of all network topologies, present in the network.

That much of data is used as logs, for tracking.
Handling that with automation seems to be cryptic. Write now I am dumping logs to directly to a file. But yes implementing paging wil be a good option

Comment: Good luck... BTW, parsing a 50Mb worth of JSON-data is going to be _very_ CPU-intensive, if you use the pure Tcl parser. So, be sure to use the recent `tcllib`, which comes with a native JSON-parser implemented in C.